# Hibernate Criteria Getsession().save/update/delete/merge

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I am new to hibernate `Criteria` and I am aiming to write a functions with `Criteria` using less code.

how can I make it from this:

```
public List<Test> listOfTest(Map map) {
    String testName = map.get("testName") == null ? "" : (String) map.get("testName");
    List list = null;
    Transaction trns = null;
    Session sess = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    try {
        trns = sess.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Test.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.like("testName", testName, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        crit.addOrder(Order.asc("testName"));
        list = crit.list();
        sess.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (trns != null) {
            trns.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        sess.flush();
        sess.close();
    }
    return list;
}
```

to this:

```
public List<Test> listOfTest(Map map) {
        String testName = map.get("testName") == null ? "" : (String) map.get("testName");
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Test.class);
        crit.add(Restrictions.like("testName", testName, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        crit.addOrder(Order.asc("testName"));}
    return list ;
}
```

Comment: Hibernate/spring transaction annotations

Comment: can you give me a good source sir. thanks